# How to convert h160 address to ss58 address?

Tags: evm, wallet, address, ss58

I am a dApp developer in Astar.
I want to convert EVM(h160) address to Substrate(ss58) address to implement the UI like the subscan page.

https://astar.subscan.io/account/0xCF9C880D696AF9622b22bC0e5f9e0f8b3CA1a3F2
⇅
https://astar.subscan.io/account/Z8QyRcUaVzozkL8FDFAeAM6c7FzqN2Y1PpbaPG2nK4vcsps

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to convert `H160` to `SS58` directly.

[image]

As you can see, `H160` is not the native account format of Astar. They have only established connections between their Substrate account and Ethereum account.

I suggest asking about how Astar created this relationship.

Here is the algorithm that Astar used.

- https://github.com/AstarNetwork/Astar/blob/ebbc59d20a90cba74013efaf0066e22dcc89c797/runtime/astar/src/lib.rs#L786C39-L786C59
- https://docs.rs/pallet-evm/latest/pallet_evm/struct.HashedAddressMapping.html

Follow this to get the mapping `H256` of `H160` then convert the `H256` to `SS58`